# RegEx for excluding a specifying group of tag within set of tags

Tags: regex, html-parsing, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy, regex-group

```
<info>
<owner>
<p>Owners:</p>
<p>1. New Owner_1</p>
<p>2. New Owner_2</p>
</owner>
<addons>
<p>Name of dog: Alex</p>
<p>1. Text blah blah blah</p>
<p>2. Text blah blah blah</p>
<p>3. Text blah blah blah</p>
<p>4. Text blah blah blah</p>
<p>OR MORE Text blah blah blah</p>
</addons>
<p>DETAILS</p>
<p>1. Vicky Mears 1st dog's owner.</p>
<p>2. Paul Nash 2nd dog's owner.</p>
<p>3. Dog found last Apr. 2016</p>
</info>
```

Hi, i'm currently studying regex for school. My teacher points out a problem at the above shown structure.

He asks us how to look for:

```
<p>1. ...</p>
<p>2. ...</p>
<p>3. ...</p>
```

but not inside:

```
<p>DETAILS</p>
<p>1. Vicky Mears 1st dog's owner.</p>
<p>2. Paul Nash 2nd dog's owner.</p>
<p>3. Dog found last Apr. 2016</p>
</info>
```

The `<owner></owner>, <addons></addons>` tag varies at some point so specifying mother tag is not necessary just exclude everything found in:

```
<p>DETAILS</p>
<p>1. Vicky Mears 1st dog's owner.</p>
<p>2. Paul Nash 2nd dog's owner.</p>
<p>3. Dog found last Apr. 2016</p>
</info>
```

I use this

```
(?s)<p>DETAILS</p>(.*?)</info>
```

but it finds the one I want to exclude.

Can anyone help me about this problem? stackoverflow is my last resort.

PS: searching purposes only using RegEx in Notepad++ v6.8.3

Comment: Interesting read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: `@omijn` i saw this post about a week ago but evaluated it to the best of my knowledge and found out that this is not the one i've been looking for... but then, thank you for your effort to reply.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `@Ibrahim` I use this `(?s)<p>DETAILS</p>(.*?)</info>` but it finds the one I want to exclude. By the way im new to RegEx.

Comment: please add any relevant information to the question by using "Edit"

Comment: @Lonely Neuron can you elaborate what you meant by your question sir? Please?

Comment: Np++ Scintilla regex are close to PCRE, then you may find [regex101](https://regex101.com/) useful. Using _dot match new lines_ and _global_ flags this regex `<p>[^\n]+(?=.+<p>DETAILS<)` do the job (but has poor performances). You can use replacement instead, with pattern `<p>DETAILS.+|<(?!p|\/p>)(?:.(?!<p))+`, replacement being an empty string, with both flags used previously.

Comment: Moved a comment to the question

Comment: `@Stphane` Hi, I tested the pattern `<p>DETAILS.+|<(?!p|\/p>)(?:.(?!<p))+` and yes it will remove most of the mother tags but still retains the information under DETAILS... anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
<p>DETAILS[\s\S]*|(<p>.*?<\/p>)|.*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IB9QFu/1/

The idea is to use the boolean `OR |` to match first whatever occurs after `DETAILS`, then start matching `<p>..</p>`.

You could in - notepad++ - `Replace All` with `$1` to keep only the required `<p>..</p>`.

If you would like to test it in `RegExr`, use this code

```
/<p>DETAILS[\s\S]*|(<p>.*?<\/p>)|^.*$/gm
```

Comment: This is the answer i've been looking for... thanks `@Ibrahim` there are thousands of lines to check and it's been a hassle for me to check one by one under `<p>DETAILS</p>` and YES! thank you so much!

Comment: `@Ibrahim` good day sir, I have a follow up question, your code works just fine but, if i had a structure with two `<p>DETAILS</p>` on it will exclude everything do you have a code just to stop at `<p>DETAILS</p>....</info>` only? Its so much to ask but i am hoping you can me help out again.

Comment: Hi @Lucas, in this case, you could specify a length, say `120`, and add `</info>` after it. This will be make it impossible for the first one to reach `</info>`, and possible for the second one. check it out here:  https://regex101.com/r/IB9QFu/2/

Comment: `@Ibrahim` I never thought of specifying a max number. Dude you're great! Thanks.